# Create "Sets" within the same table based on multi-column criteria

Tags: sql-server

For every unique combination of BoxId and Revision with a single UnitTypeId of 1 and a single UnitTypeId of 2 both having a NULL SetNumber, assign a SetNumber of 1.

Table and data setup:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[UnitTypes]') AND type in (N'U'))
Drop Table dbo.UnitTypes
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Tracking]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Tracking]
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.UnitTypes
    (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Notes varchar(80)
    )
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tracking
    (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    BoxId int NOT NULL,
    Revision int NOT NULL,
    UnitValue int NULL,
    UnitTypeId int NULL,
    SetNumber int NULL
    )
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tracking ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Tracking PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Id
    )
GO  
Insert Into dbo.UnitTypes (Id, Notes) Values (1, 'X Coord'),
                                             (2, 'Y Coord'),
                                             (3, 'Weight'),
                                             (4, 'Length')
Go
Insert Into dbo.Tracking (BoxId, Revision, UnitValue, UnitTypeId, SetNumber)
              Values (1165, 1, 150, 1, NULL),
                     (1165, 1, 1477, 2, NULL),
                     (1165, 1, 31, 4, NULL),
                     (1166, 1, 425, 1, 1),
                     (1166, 1, 1146, 2, 1),
                     (1166, 1, 438, 1, NULL),
                     (1166, 1, 1163, 2, NULL),
                     (1167, 1, 560, 1, NULL),
                     (1167, 1, 909, 2, NULL),
                     (1167, 1, 12763, 3, NULL),
                     (1168, 1, 21, 1, NULL),
                     (1168, 1, 13109, 3, NULL)
```

The ideal results would be:

```
Id  BoxId   Revision    UnitValue   UnitTypeId  SetNumber
 1   1165          1          150            1          1
 2   1165          1         1477            2          1
 3   1165          1           31            4          1
 4   1166          1          425            1          1
 5   1166          1         1146            2          1
 6   1166          1          438            1       NULL <--NULL Because there is already an existing Set
 7   1166          1         1163            2       NULL <--NULL Because there is already an existing Set
 8   1167          1          560            1          1
 9   1167          1          909            2          1
 10  1167          1        12763            3          1
 11  1168          1           21            1       NULL <--NULL Because there is not exactly one UnitTypeId of 1 and exactly one UnitTypeId of 2 for this BoxId\Revision combination.
 12  1168          1        13109            3       NULL <--NULL Because there is not exactly one UnitTypeId of 1 and exactly one UnitTypeId of 2 for this BoxId\Revision combination.
```

**EDIT:** 
The question is how can I update the SetNumber, given the constraints above, using pure TSQL?

Comment: The question is how to accomplish this using sql. I've tried many things but always end up with temp tables. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this update.

Comment: Just like in math class in school, it's best to **show your work**.  If it looks like you haven't done anything and just came to SO to post a list of requirements and have someone do everything for you, you are less likely to get help from the more experienced folks.

Comment: Excellent point. Although I've been hitting my head against this issue all day now and out of desperation I've turned to SO hoping someone has a clever solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do this with a subquery that demands all conditions are met:

```
update  t1
set     SetNumber = 1
from    dbo.Tracking t1
where   SetNumber is null
        and 1 = 
        (
        select  case 
                when count(case when t2.UnitTypeId = 1 then 1 end) <> 1 then 0
                when count(case when t2.UnitTypeId = 2 then 1 end) <> 1 then 0
                when count(t2.SetNumber) <> 0 then 0
                else 1 
                end
        from    dbo.Tracking t2
        where   t1.BoxId = t2.BoxId
                and t1.Revision = t2.Revision
        )
```

The `count(t2.SetNumber)` is a bit tricky: this will only count rows where `SetNumber` is not `null`. So this meets the criterion that no other set with the same `(BoxId, Revision)` exists.

Comment: I love the simplicity of this. I'm so programmed against subqueries that my brain filters them out as a possible solution. I'm dealing with small data sets so performance is a non-issue. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, it returns the same results that you gave. The `WITH` statement sets up a CTE to query from. The `ROW_NUMBER()` function is partitioning function that does what you want:

```
;WITH BoxSets AS (
SELECT
    ID
    ,BoxId
    ,Revision
    ,UnitValue
    ,UnitTypeId
    ,CASE WHEN UnitTypeId IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ValidUnit
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BoxID,UnitTypeID ORDER BY BoxID,UnitTypeID,UnitValue ) SetNumber
FROM Tracking
)

SELECT 
    b.ID
    ,b.BoxId
    ,b.Revision
    ,b.UnitValue
    ,b.UnitTypeId
    ,CASE ISNULL(b1.ValidUnits,0) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE CASE b.SetNumber WHEN 1 THEN b.SetNumber ELSE NULL END END
FROM BoxSets AS b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
             BoxID
             ,SUM(ValidUnit) AS ValidUnits
             FROM BoxSets
             GROUP BY BoxId
             HAVING SUM(ValidUnit) > 1) AS b1 ON b.BoxId = b1.BoxId
```

Comment: The OP asks to mark when there's exactly one `1` and one `2`.  This answer would accept groups with two or even three `UnitTypeId = 1` ?

Comment: Simple fix, just reversed the condition in the `CASE` statement.

Comment: This is very close but it doesn't exclude the BoxId 1166 series.

Comment: @MichaelMinton, actually based on the sample data (and data I've inserted) it does. Can't format the results correctly here, but I see exactly what you posted as the ideal.